# get value from custom directive in a controller function - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code, i want to receive the ng-module value from custom directive in the controller function:

The *getName* function is the function when i am trying to get the value..

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller("Controller", function ($scope) {
$scope.getName = function() {
return $scope.name;
};
})
.controller("EditController", function($scope) {
$scope.editingMode = true;
})
.directive("newName", function ($parse) {
return {
template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
};
});


<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <h1>Hello, {{ getName() }}</h1>

      <div ng-controller="EditController">
        <new-name ng-show="editingMode"></new-name>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

your `getName()` function is in `parent` controller and your child controller overwriting the `name` variable (JS prototypical inheritance).,

You should model bind(`use dot(.) in  your bindings`) your parent scope properties to avoid getting overwritten. also you should define `restrict type` for directive and should pass the variable from parent HTML.

Here is working code below :

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller("Controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.name = {
      n: ''
    }
    $scope.getName = function() {
      return $scope.name.n;
    };
  })
  .controller("EditController", function($scope) {
    $scope.editingMode = true;
  })
  .directive("newName", function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
      },
      template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>Hello, {{ getName()}}</h1>
    <div ng-controller="EditController">
      <new-name ng-show="editingMode" name="name.n"></new-name>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

FurtherI suggest there is no need of 2 controllers in your code, one is enough though, and will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }} </h1>

        <div ng-controller="EditController">
            <new-name ng-show="editingMode" name="name"></new-name>
        </div>
    </div>
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller("Controller", ['$scope' , function ($scope ) {
        $scope.getName = function (name) {
            return $scope.name = name;
        };

    }])
    .controller("EditController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.editingMode = true;
        $scope.$watch('name', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.getName(newVal);
        });
    })
    .directive("newName", function () {

        return {
            transclude :true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name: '=',
            },
            template: 'Write name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" >'
        };
    });
```